# Bootstrap typeahead and forms - Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I have having issues with Twitter's bootstrap type ahead. So far everything is going smoothly, however when I drop the value the user selected in the typeahead into a form and post it by the update function to a script I get the below error

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string in

The below is my php and mysql code

```
$race_name = print_r($_POST['race'],true);
echo gettype($race_name);
echo $race_name;
$race_query= mysqli_query($dbc."
    SELECT CITY, DATE, NAME, STATE
    FROM RACE_INFO
    WHERE NAME LIKE '$race_name'")or die ('Could not find race: '.mysqli_error());
```

As you can see i have tried to force the variable to be a string. When I echo the gettype it confirms that it is a string, but I am still receiving the error.

Comment: are you echoing $race_query ?

Comment: the construction of $race_query is where the error is so it does not execute echo $race_query

Comment: Why are you assigning the return value from `print_r`?

Comment: what are you getting in var_dump($race_name) ?

Comment: Please post the rest of that error message as well as the code around the given location

Comment: vardump give me -> string(18) "Race to Wrigley 5k" and the rest of the error is <file name> + "on line 21"